# Kafka Controller could not connect to brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

I've a 3 node Kafka cluster(version 0.10.1.0). I've followed the steps on [kafka security documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#security). Here are the related configurations of one of my Kafka servers.

```
listeners=SSL://myhostname:9093
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
advertised.listeners=SSL://myhostname:9093
# In order to enable hostname verification
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS

ssl.client.auth=required

# certificate file locations
ssl.keystore.location=/location/server1.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=changeit
ssl.key.password=changeit
ssl.truststore.location=/location/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=changeit

# Supported TLS versions
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

I've defined 3 different keystores for all my Kafka servers and signed them with the same CA. When I start the Kafka servers the controller log constantly logs the following warning log.

```
WARN [Controller-0-to-broker-2-send-thread], Controller 0's connection to broker host3:9093 (id: 2 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to host3:9093 (id: 2 rack: null) failed
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:230)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:182)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:181)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
WARN [Controller-0-to-broker-0-send-thread], Controller 0's connection to broker host1:9093 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to host1:9093 (id: 0 rack: null) failed
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:230)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:182)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:181)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
WARN [Controller-0-to-broker-1-send-thread], Controller 0's connection to broker host2:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to host2:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) failed
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.awaitReady$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:83)
    at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingReady$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:93)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:230)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.liftedTree1$1(ControllerChannelManager.scala:182)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:181)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

It seems to me more serious than a warning.

Do you have any idea what may be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I identified the problem, it is about the certificate creation. Refer to [Confluent's documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html) it says:

> Ensure that common name (CN) matches exactly with the fully qualified
>   domain name (FQDN) of the server. The client compares the CN with the
>   DNS domain name to ensure that it is indeed connecting to the desired
>   server, not a malicious one.

I regenerate the certificates and it worked!

Comment: I tried maintaining same CN as FQDN is but I am still getting the error. Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798687/integrating-security-to-kafka-1-0-with-ssl-enabled